# Google Translate Original Text H1 Tag affecting google search results

Tags: javascript, html, google-translate, google-search

I have been using JS google translate library to translate my site

```
<script src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script async type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, autoDisplay: false }, 'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>
```

it's creating a H1 tag with "Original text"

```
<div id="goog-gt-tt" class="skiptranslate" dir="ltr">
   <div class="top" style="padding: 8px; float: left; width: 100%;">
      <h1 class="title gray">Original Text</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="middle" style="padding: 8px;">
      <div class="original-text"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

It is not affecting the page or anything. But the problem is that showing on Google search results. Do you know how to avoid this?

[Google search results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOgHQ.png)